# Set min height for border layout in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is a first time that I am dabbling into fixing an issue that was written in extJS.
I have searched all day for an answer and despite the fact that I learned a lot about extJS I could not find an answer to my question. 
I am working on a layout:border and I want to set a minimum height for my west region. I understand that a specific height can be set for north and south but I need my other regions to have a larger height so that the whole page can be scrolled up or down. 
The code that I trying to fix is a rather large app but the part that handles the viewport is as followed. I really appreciate any help or hint that you might have.

```
var panel = new Ext.Viewport({
            id: 'viewport',
            cls: 'theme2',
            scope: this,
            title: 'Wedding Planner',
            layout: 'border',
            monitorResize: true,
            defaults: {
              collapsible: true,
              split: true
            },
            items: [{
                region: 'north',
                xtype: 'panel',
                bodyStyle: 'background: transparent;',
                collapsible: false,
                collapsed: false,
                border:false,  
                split: false,    
                margins: '0 0 0 0',
                style: 'z-index: -1000',
                height: Ext.get('header').getHeight(),
                footer: true
            },this.appTabs,{
                region:'west',
                width: 330,
                collapsible: false,
                id: 'west-container',
                layout: 'fit',
                cls: 'mw-background',

                margins: '0 0 5 5',
                items: [
                    this.weddingPlan
                ]      
            }]

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `minHeight` configs for your problem.

Comment: I did try that in my layoutConfig but it didnt work. It doesnt seem that it extended the page nor any scroll bar appeared. Thanks for the hint though